# Hijacking the Chrome file picker

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to create a Chrome extension that allows you to resize images just before you upload them. So after the user picks a file in the file picker, I'd like to show a popup for some options, generate a resized image and fill that one in instead. Would that be possible in a Chrome extension (never made one before)? The main thing I'd need is an elegant way to hook into the file picker or just hijack all input[type=file]'s.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should "Hijack" it before the Chrome gets the alert that it should display a file picker dialog.

What I mean is this your script jumps in between, Executes and then says `OK, Chrome, I want a file!` not the website. the script gets the image. Resizes it. then submits it to the website anyhow. Like save it in a temp location then provide the site input tag with the temp file location..

Seems legit I think..